# Android, Multiple ImageButtons that play an audio clip

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am making an app for a local band. On one screen there are two ImageButtons when clicked they should play different audio clips. The top ImageButton plays the clip great. Although the bottom ImageButton plays the song that the top ImageButton is playing. I'm not getting any errors in the code so i thinkim just not formatting correctly. Thanks

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

   ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.placeyouknow);
   btn.setOnClickListener(this);


   ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.fallen);
   btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

}
public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.thatplaceyouknow);
   mp.start();


}
public void onClick1(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fallen);
    mp.start();


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

why would onClick1 ever get called? haha, try something like this:

```
 public void onClick (View v) {
   switch v.getId() {
   case R.id.placeyouknow:
     mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.thatplaceyouknow);
     mp.start();
     break;
   case R.id.fallen:
     mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fallen);
     mp.start();
     break;
   }
 }
```

cheers

Comment: Thanks, but why is it telling me that btn and btn1 cannot be resolved to a variable?

Comment: It looks like he meant `R.id.placeyouknow` and `R.id.fallen` as in your layout IDs, and not the local-scope variables `btn` and `btn1`, respectively, that are long gone by the call of `onClick`.

Comment: @Ribose is right, my mistake. I wrote the code in a hurry at work. replace btn and btn1 with their respective XML id's and you should be just fine